# Powershell Call Specific CSV Based On HostName

Tags: csv, powershell

hoping someone can help out as im banging my head against the wall a little here ...
I have a simple CSV file, 2 columns, 1 for HostName and 1 for Password.
For example;

HostName,Password

Computer1,Password1

Computer2,Password2

etc

What I need to do is read the password from the CSV, based on the HostName of the device the script is running on.
This is for BitLocker PIN encryption and so instead of me specifying the PIN in my current PowerShell script, it would read the value from the CSV and encrypt using that.

Cheers guys,

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried that is not working. This would just be a case of `import-csv` and `where-object`.

Comment: I'll try to behave here ! : ) Please show us some cdoe, what you have tried, what failed, etc

Comment: This is the PS currently used to encrypt. However where I am having issues is with querying a CSV for the password based on HOSTNAME instead of setting a "Default" one and changing post encryption.


$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "DEFAULT" -AsPlainText -Force

THEN

Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -Pin $SecureString -TPMandPinProtector -SkipHardWareTest

Answer (score 1):

In a very general way, you can grab your object (CSV) file and filter with where-object. Once that is stuffed into a variable, you can just call the property with a "."

```
$Comp1 = Get-MyCSV  | Where {$_.HostName -eq Computer1}
$Comp1.Password
```

Comment: This is the PS currently used to encrypt. However where I am having issues is with querying a CSV for the password based on HOSTNAME instead of setting a "Default" one and changing post encryption. $SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "DEFAULT" -AsPlainText -Force THEN Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -Pin $SecureString -TPMandPinProtector -SkipHardWareTest –

Answer (score 0):

Resolved now thanks for the input chaps.

$InSecureString = Import-Csv "C:\EncryptionPasswords.csv"
$BitLockerPassword = $InSecureString.Where({$PSItem.ComputerName -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME}).Password
$BitLockerPassword

Then called the $BitLockerPassword variable and converted to SecureString.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `Where-Object` every time you need to retrieve a password based on hostname, would be to create a `hashtable` from the values:

```
$LookupTable = @{}
Import-Csv .\passwords.csv |ForEach-Object { 
    $LookupTable[$_.HostName] = ConvertTo-SecureString $_.Password -AsPlainText -Force 
}
```

Now you can retrieve the corresponding password as a secure string directly from the hashtable:

```
$MachineName = $env:ComputerName
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:" -Pin $LookupTable[$MachineName] -TPMandPinProtector
```